# How can I convert strings like \xd0\x9d to a proper text

Tags: string, actionscript-3, utf-8, utf8-decode, flash-cc

I have some text like \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5 which I want to display as normal text (I guess it's utf-8 literal and Cyrillic). I tried it using xammp on windows:

```
<?php 

    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Content-Language: ru");
    print('\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5');

?>
```

How can I do this using AS3 or any other program on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes.

This code:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Language: ru");
print("\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5");

?>
```

Returns this:

```
Наше
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to escape the **'\'** like so:

```
print('\\xd0\\x9d\\xd0\\xb0\\xd1\\x88\\xd0\\xb5');
```

if it is very combersome, you can use str_replace like so:

```
$text='\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5';
$text= str_replace("\x","\\x",$text);
print($text);
```

Comment: I tried it and it output same text: \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5 thank you for your answer.

Comment: were you expecting some-thign else? if so, can you show what the expected output looks like.